# How can I access a scope with bracket notation?

Tags: syntax, coldfusion, scope

As input for a function I get a string scopename like `FORM` or `COOKIE`.
How can I access these top level scopes in a bracket notation?

I'm looking for something like:

```
var myScope = "FORM";
global[myScope];
```

Obviously that doesn't work though :)

(I'm not looking for any kind of `eval` function, I'd rather `switch` through the string manually to get the right scope than an `eval` function...)

**EDIT**

Functionality is needed so I can call an easy/accessible function early on in a request to identify bad requests that are either sending the wrong kind of data or are just not sending the required data.

for example I'll call the following function as early as possible in a request that needs the variables `FORM.data1:numeric`, `FORM.data2:bit` and `COOKIE.data3:string`:

```
<cfset require({
  "FORM" : {
    "data1":"numeric",
    "data2":"bit"
  },
  "COOKIE":{
    "data3":"string"
  } 
})>
```

I'm aware that the following might have been a bit easier:

```
<cfset require({
  "FORM.data1":"numeric",
  "FORM.data2":"bit",
  "COOKIE.data3":"string"
})>
```

and than just use `isDefined` but I need some more flexibility for other functionality.

Comment: You don't. Scopes are already global. **Why are you trying to do this?** (There's probably a better way.)

Comment: Use Evaluate(). This kind of thing is what it's there for and unless this code is in a particularly tight loop, there won't be a performance problem. You will want to be mindful of sanitizing your input if it can be influenced by user input.

Comment: Searching through all the scopes seems to defeat the purpose of scoping the variable to begin with.

Comment: @Busches I'm not searching through all scopes, I'm searching through a defined scope, the one given in the arguments of the function

Comment: @PeterBoughton I'm creating a function that can evaluate whether all the required variables are available and of correct type, if not handle the request differently, with a `400 Bad request` for example

Comment: So, you're creating a REST API that can accept its input via different avenues?

Comment: @PeterBoughton See the question edit, I've added the reason why I need the functionality

Comment: So, what's wrong with `cfparam`?  See my answer...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, the simplest solution is just to write it like this:

```
<cfparam name="form.data1"   type="numeric" />
<cfparam name="form.data2"   type="numeric" />
<cfparam name="cookie.data3" type="string" />
```

However, if you find that too verbose, you can use your existing data structure, like this:

```
<cfset require({
  "FORM" : {
    "data1":"numeric",
    "data2":"bit"
  },
  "COOKIE":{
    "data3":"string"
  } 
})>


<cffunction name="require" returntype="void" output=false >
    <cfargument name="Scopes" type="Struct" required />

    <cfloop item="local.CurScope" collection=#Arguments.Scopes#>
        <cfloop item="local.CurVar" collection=#Arguments.Scopes[CurScope]#>
            <cfparam name="#CurScope#.#CurVar#" type="#Arguments.Scopes[CurScope][CurVar]#" />
        </cfloop>
    </cfloop>
</cffunction>
```

Alternatively, there's an even simpler way of doing it than that:

```
<cfset require
    ( "FORM.data1"   : "numeric"
    , "FORM.data2"   : "bit"
    , "COOKIE.data3" : "string"
    )>

<cffunction name="require" returntype="void" output=false >

    <cfloop item="local.ArgName" collection=#Arguments#>
        <cfparam name="#ArgName#" type="#Arguments[ArgName]#" />
    </cfloop>

</cffunction>
```

You imply that you need the unscoped name for other functionality, in which case you simply do `<cfset UnscopedName = ListRest(ArgName,'.') />`

Comment: You're right, this does look cleaner, especially like the simplicity of the last example.

Comment: Peter, what is required to run the bottom example? I can't seem to get it to work in CF9. Thanks.

Comment: _"I can't seem to get it to work"_ - and...? What happens when you try? Does it give an error message, or simply unexpected results?

Answer (score 5):

You can use `structGet()` for this.

```
var theformscope = structGet('form');
```

More info on structGet is available in the ColdFusion docs: http://help.adobe.com/en_US/ColdFusion/9.0/CFMLRef/WSc3ff6d0ea77859461172e0811cbec22c24-7f03.html

Comment: This answer is correct, but I still maintain that passing a string of a scope name is unlikely to be the right solution to whatever is being done here.

Comment: You're probably right, but there isn't much info to work with so I'm just answering the question that was asked.  I have only used this technique once, and it was for an object that abstracted a scope.  The scope could be any so it was actually beneficial to send in the scope name as a string in ColdSpring then use structGet() to grab a handle to it.

Comment: Yeah, that comment was more aimed at people who might come in future, and just use the function without thinking. In general it's probably a better idea to pass the scope itself instead of (or as well as) the name.

Comment: I completely forgot about that one :). Nice solution.

Answer (score 1):

I don't believe it's possible without using the `Evaluate` functions. Scopes are at the top level of the chain so to speak, so there is no dot notation ahead of them.